# Replacing fuses on inverter PCB

Tags: inverter, fuses

I have an inverter that stopped working (after the 12 V DC power source was repeatedly connected and disconnected through a relay with a false contact). When I opened it, I saw some fuses that are burned, so I want to replace them.

My first question is why there are four 25 A fuses in parallel. Isn't it easier to place one 100 A fuse? Why have they done it like this? I ask because I would like to replace with a single fuse since it will be easier for me, unless the four fuses are mandatory.

How can I replace these fuses? I am terrible at soldering. The fuses seem to be welded pretty good because of the involved currents. I can't seem to remove the fuses. Is it feasible to just weld a 100 A fuse to the back?

What is the copper sheet to the right of the fuses?

Photo of the fuses (I ripped one out already):

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I were you I'd quickly check for short circuits downstream the fuses before spending time in replacing them. Those are heavy duty, damn slow car style fuses, I'm afraid they are not blown just on a transient.

Answer (score 2):

They probably put four fuses in to spread out the current across the plane since putting in a single 100A fuse would concentrate the current into an unacceptably small width and compromise the integrity of the board or trace right by the fuse and/or heat up the fuse enough to drop its current rating by an unacceptable amount.  You will need to replace all four fuses with four 25A fuses.

The copper sheet to the right could be to distribute current more evenly across the fuses by acting as a busbar and/or a heatsink to mitigate the effects of heat generation in the plane mentioned previously.  What's on the underside of that board?

Comment: I have added an image for the backside. There is so much solder there. Not sure how to melt it to get the fuses out/in

Comment: Break off the old fuses by wiggling them until they break. Then get a big soldering iron - you’ll need to pump a lot of heat into the area. Make sure to use lots of fresh solder to flux and couple the heat into the joint.

Comment: A hot air gun would work well to melt all the solder for the fuses. But it looks like they *might* be inserted into sockets.